# Why am I getting an error from this boto3 syntax?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am attempting to write a tool in python to add or remove users from an EC2 security group on AWS. The tool is meant to enable/disable access to a server-side private system for specific people via specific IP addresses. I've almost got it working, but I'm running into a problem with the remove_user() function when it is optimised.

The add_user() function is working as intended:

```
# add the user to the security group
def add_user(self):
    # clear existing permissions if there are any
    self.remove_user()
    # update the security group with the new rules for username and ip address
    self.group.authorize_ingress(
        IpPermissions=[
            {   # http
                'FromPort': 82,
                'IpProtocol': 'tcp',
                'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': self.user.ip, 'Description': self.user.name}],
                'ToPort': 82
            },{ # https
                'FromPort': 446,
                'IpProtocol': 'tcp',
                'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': self.user.ip, 'Description': self.user.name}],
                'ToPort': 446
            }
        ])
```

The remove_user() function also works as intended when written as follows:

```
# remove the user from the security group
def remove_user(self):
    # searchs for the user's name in the security group and removes it if it exists
    for rule in self.rules:
        # apply to ingress rules only
        if (not rule['IsEgress']):
            # check if the rule is for the user
            if (rule['Description'] == self.user.name):
                id = rule['SecurityGroupRuleId']
                client.revoke_security_group_ingress(GroupId=self.group_id, SecurityGroupRuleIds=[id])
```

However, this is making multiple AWS CLI calls, and I would rather it make only a single call. Here is the optimised definition:

```
# remove the user from the security group
def remove_user(self):
    ids = []
    # searchs for the user's name in the security group and removes it if it exists
    for rule in self.rules:
        # apply to ingress rules only
        if (not rule['IsEgress']):
            # check if the rule is for the user
            if (rule['Description'] == self.user.name):
                ids.append(rule['SecurityGroupRuleId'])
    client.revoke_security_group_ingress(GroupId=self.group_id, SecurityGroupRuleIds=ids)
```

When I run the optimised function in python on the command line, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\host\src\tool_dir\tool.py", line 50, in remove_user
    client.revoke_security_group_ingress(GroupId=self.group_id, SecurityGroupRuleIds=rule_ids)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 535, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 980, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (MissingParameter) when calling the RevokeSecurityGroupIngress operation: Either 'ipPermissions' or 'securityGroupRuleIds' should be provided.
```

Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't know anything about Boto, but as a quick hint for future Python questions: please use the same "multi-line code" formatting for error messages. Python's error messages are carefully designed to look right with this formatting; in particular, they use `^` symbols to highlight parts of the code. (I also added the `boto3` tag for you.)

Comment: You are likely seeing this error in the case where none of your descriptions match, and `ids` is an empty array as a result.  The API call will treat empty arrays as not-present, so you're calling `RevokeSecurityGroupIngress` with missing options.

Comment: You see the behavior @AnonCoward describes in the 2nd example but not the first because in the first example the call is only made if there is match whereas in your second example you make the call regardless if there are any matches.

Comment: @AnonCoward is correct; adding a condition before the call does the trick.

        if (len(rule_ids) > 0):
            client.revoke_security_group_ingress(
                GroupId=self.group_id, SecurityGroupRuleIds=rule_ids)